# showing white screen when playing video

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hi 
white screen is showing if video is not in supported list. and there is no way user to go back to previous screen(navigation bar too not showing).and
when i initialize the MPMoviePlayerController their retain count is increasing to 4.

here is my code

```
mMPMovieViewCont=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:theURL];
        [theURL release];
        theURL=nil;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(movieDidFinishForOS4:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                       object:nil];

        [self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mMPMovieViewCont];
        NSLog(@"%d",[mMPMovieViewCont retainCount]);  //**here count is 4**
- (void) movieDidFinishForOS4:(NSNotification*)notification  {

mMPMovieViewCont.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime=-1.0;      
[mMPMovieViewCont dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];
NSLog(@"%d",[mMPMovieViewCont retainCount]);  //returning 3

[mMPMovieViewCont release]; 
mMPMovieViewCont = nil;
```

}

i am using ios4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not call retainCount.  It is useless in production and misleading for debugging.

The retain count is entirely irrelevant to your question, it would seem.   I'm not sure I understand exactly what "*Hi white screen is showing if video is not in supported list*" means, but it sounds like you need to check to see if the video is compatible with the device or on the approved playlist before you start playback?